# Auto start print html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Is there anyway to automatically run `javascript:window.print()` when the page finishes loading?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`<body onload="window.print()">`
or
`window.onload = function() { window.print(); }`

Comment: The second variation is the preferred method.

Comment: Why not `window.onload = window.print;`

Comment: @elipoultorak not this case specifically, but some calls for native functions that are not direct are causing "Illegal invocation" error, so this is generally discouraged so not used as much :)

Comment: @elipoultorak @jave.web `window.onload = window.print.bind();` ;)

Answer (score 21):

The following code must be put at the **end** of your HTML file so that once the content has loaded, the script will be executed and the window will print.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.print();
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: better to use `<script type="text/javascript">` rather than using the deprecated `language` attribute.

Comment: If that's not in the end of the HTML it will start the printing process before the page is loaded.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following code in your HTML page, and it will show print preview on page load.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.print();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding `<script>window.print();</script>` to the end of the page worked.

---

I didn't need the `type="text/javascript"` attribute, or even for the page to be wrapped in a `<body>` tag. However, all of my previous attempts to intuitively use the answers suggested here, of just writing `window.onload=window.print` or longer versions such as `window.onload=()=>window.print();` did not work, and of course calling print on the newly created window does not wait for the contents to load.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to open a separate window from the web browser you can use this:

```
  window.open(basePath + "Controller/Route/?ID=" + param, '_blank').print();
```